# How to insert the data into hyper-ledger fabric fabric network (block-chain) through REST APIs

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-java

I am planning to implement a block-chain based application for storing the electricity consumption records to a hyperledger fabric network.
Is there any way to insert the data through REST APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to write the smart-contract (as per your use-case) and deploy that to the hyper-ledger fabric network.
Then, you can create another application where you expose the REST endpoints. Maybe a Springboot application you can create with REST endpoints which can take the data requests and call the Smart-Contract's methods for creating the records.